# Ionic - Route change event

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I run a piece of code each time the route changes? I can't seem to find an event to bind the code to.

I need this to happen globally throughout the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$routeChangeStart`  for Ionic - Route change event.It will Broadcast before a route change. At this point the route services starts resolving all of the dependencies needed for the route change to occur.

The event called `$routeChangeSuccess`
Broadcasted after a route change has happened successfully. The resolve dependencies are now available in the current
Refer [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) for more details

**How to use $routeChangeStart in ionic?**

**app.js**

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $location) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            //print here
        });
 })
```

Comment: @Rich :Glad to help you

Comment: Wait is that `$stateChangeStart` or `$routeChangeStart`?